# Kendo Dialogue Unable to Click second TIme

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I got following code to showcase a dialogue, however the dialogue wont show up in UI after the First click.

```
$('#wayneDialog').kendoDialog({
            width: '400px',
            title: $scope.resourceString.Delete_Confirm_Title+ "'"+ name +"'?",
            closable: true,
            modal: true,
            content: $scope.resourceString.Delete_confirm_Content,
            actions: [
                {
                    text: $scope.resourceString.Yes,
                    action: $scope.onDeleteConfirm,
                    primary: true
                },
                {
                    text: $scope.resourceString.Cancel
                }
            ]
        });
```

I am not sure if I have to do anything extra in this case.

Comment: I noticed that even after I close the dialog the <div> '#wayneDialog' still has the data .

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: No Console Errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.
The Kendo Dialog was repeatedly getting initialized in my calling function.
Changed the code to initialize Kendo Dialog only once and then updated Title and Dialog before calling Kendo Dialog Open function.

Comment: Is there any way you can add the code for this? I have a kendo dialog that uses a partial view, it is only opening a single time as well but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Thank you. @TBA

Answer (score 2):

we need to destroy the div and add it again on the close event .

```
$('#wayneDialog').kendoDialog({
            width: '400px',
            title: $scope.resourceString.Delete_Confirm_Title+ "'"+ name +"'?",
            closable: true,
            modal: true,
            content: $scope.resourceString.Delete_confirm_Content,
close: function () {
                    if ($('#wayneDialog').data("kendoDialog")) {
                        $('#wayneDialog').data("kendoDialog").destroy();
                        $('<div id="wayneDialog"/>').appendTo('body');
                    }
                    return;
                }           
 actions: [
                {
                    text: $scope.resourceString.Yes,
                    action: $scope.onDeleteConfirm,
                    primary: true
                },
                {
                    text: $scope.resourceString.Cancel
                }
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `visible: true` option explicitly should do the trick:

```
$('#wayneDialog').kendoDialog({
            visible: true,
            width: '400px',
            title: $scope.resourceString.Delete_Confirm_Title+ "'"+ name +"'?",
            closable: true,
            modal: true,
            content: $scope.resourceString.Delete_confirm_Content,
            actions: [
                {
                    text: $scope.resourceString.Yes,
                    action: $scope.onDeleteConfirm,
                    primary: true
                },
                {
                    text: $scope.resourceString.Cancel
                }
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Kendo for Angular.
My issue was that I had the Kendo Dialog service generate any component, which may itself have a div with kendoDialogContainer inside it (for creating dialogs).

This lead to two or more existing in the DOM, and so only the lowest level seemed to function. Removing child instances of it seemed to work.

(Not sure why a Global one cannot exist, seems a bit odd)